# Video Uploads in PHP, can't find upload directory?

Tags: php, video, upload

im using this php video upload script. i have set my directory path to a folder called video which i have created with the same directory as the php file. But i can not find the video being uploaded.

It is not going to the directory i have asked it to? Why is this can someone please help me.

I am not receiving any errors.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<form action="upload_videos_process.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

php file:

```
<?php

//This handles the maximum size for the video file in kbs

define ("MAX_SIZE","500");

//This function reads the extension of the file to ensure that it is an video file

function getExtension($str) {

$i = strrpos($str,".");

if (!$i) { return ""; }

$l = strlen($str) - $i;

$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);

return $ext;

}

//This variable handles an error and won't upload the file if there is a problem with it

$errors=0;

//checks if the form has been submitted

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))

{

//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading

$video=$_FILES['video']['name'];

//if it is not empty

if ($video)

{

//get the original name of the file from the clients machine

$video_filename = stripslashes($_FILES['video']['name']);

$video_extension = getExtension($filename);

$video_extension = strtolower($extension);

//if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not upload the file, otherwise we will do more tests

if (($video_extension != "mpeg") && ($video_extension != "avi") && ($video_extension != "flv") && ($video_extension != "mov"))

{

echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';

$errors=1;

}

else

{

//get the size of the video

$size=filesize($_FILES['video']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)

{

echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';

$errors=1;

}

//give the video a unique name in case a video already exists with the name on the server
$video_name=time().'.'.$extension;

//assign a folder to save the video to on your server

$newname="video/".$video_name;

//verify that the video has been loaded

$copied = copy($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $newname);

if (!$copied)

{

echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessful!</h1>';

$errors=1;

}}}}

//If no errors registered, print the success message

if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors)

{

echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe your errors are suppressed in `php.ini`, try to add before script: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`

Comment: after that piece of code it still doesn't display any errors or anything after going to the processing page it just is blank.

Comment: It smells `post_max_size` error, it is really very silent error..

Answer (score 0):

You've blindly assumed everything's working perfectly. Things fail. First step: check if the upload actually did anything:

```
if ($_FILES['video']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['video']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

As well, don't use `copy()` on the upload file, once you've verified the upload succeeded. There's [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) for a reason - it has extra security checks to ensure that the file hasn't been tampered with on the server, and it actually **MOVES** the file. copy() can kill performance, especially on large files, since you're duplicating the file, instead of just doing some filesystem housekeeping.

You're also trusting the user to not tamper with the filename. There is **NOTHING** to prevent a malicious user from doing `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.avi` before uploading, and your script will happily accept that .exe, because its filename has simply been changed. Use server-side mime-detection (e.g http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php[enter link description here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php)) to get around this. **NEVER** trust **ANYTHING** from a user.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your php configuration does not allow to upload big files. Try setting

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

or even larger than 500M in php.ini & also as ppl mention here in comments, enable the errors

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', 8191);
```